# Redshift - Group Level Permissions on a Schema

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum, database-metadata

I created two Groups (Confirmed using `SELECT groname FROM pg_group`)

- Test_Group_A
- Test_Group_AB

Created two External Schemas (Confirmed using `SELECT schemaname FROM svv_external_schemas`)

- External_Schema_A
- External_Schema_B

Granted permissions to these groups on external schemas, as follows:

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA External_Schema_A TO GROUP Test_Group_A;

GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA External_Schema_A TO GROUP Test_Group_AB;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA External_Schema_B TO GROUP Test_Group_AB;
```

Using metadata, how do I get the list of

- Schemas that `Test_Group_X` and `Test_Group_XY` can access

OR

- Groups that have access to `External_Schema_X` and `External_Schema_Y`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            pg_get_userbyid(b.nspowner)::text AS objowner,
            b.nspname::text AS objname,
            TRIM(SPLIT_PART(array_to_string(b.nspacl, ','), ',', NS.n))::text AS access_control_list_string
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    oid,
                    generate_series(1, array_upper(nspacl, 1)) AS n
                FROM
                    pg_catalog.pg_namespace
            )
            ns
            INNER JOIN
                pg_catalog.pg_namespace B
                ON b.oid = ns.oid
                AND ns.n <= array_upper(b.nspacl, 1)
    )
WHERE
    objname = '<external_schema_name>'
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I would think would be to operate as a member of these groups and test the permissions.  The easiest way to "become" another user (while connected as a superuser) is "set session authorization 'user_name';".  This will give you the rights and authorization of this user.  When done you can "reset session authorization;".

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I updated my question. I am looking for verification using metadata.